# Numpy: Function to take arrays a and b and return array c with elements 0:b[0] with value a[0], values b[0]:b[1] with value a[1], and so on

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have two arrays:

```
a = np.asarray([0,1,2])
b = np.asarray([3,7,10])
```

Is there a fast way to create:

```
c = np.asarray([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2])
#  index             3       7     10
```

This can be done using a for loop but I wonder if there is a fast internal numpy function that achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to get the successive differences, [`r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to add the first `b` value and [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to duplicate the values:

```
a = np.asarray([0, 1, 2])
b = np.asarray([3, 7, 10])

c = np.repeat(a, np.r_[b[0], np.diff(b)])
```

Output: `array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])`